# Stuck Faucet Handles - How do I remove

Tags: faucet

[image]Can anyone tell me how to remove these faucet handles?  I have removed the allen screws and removed the faucet handles.  But then I assumed the cones under the handles woudl screw off, but I cannot get them to budge.  Is there a trick to this?

I do not know the make/model.  I have attached a picture above that shows the hot and cold faucet after I removed the handles.  How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Can you provide model numbers and brand, or photos or both?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to put the handles back on and turn them counter clockwise to unscrew the rest of the part that held the ceramic unit that needed to be replaced.  Now the problem is getting the ceramic unit unscrewed, but I hope spraying them with WD-40 a few times will loosen them up.

Comment: After about a quarter of a turn counter-clockwise, the nut underneath the sink also started to turn. My solution: I held the T-valve firmly and continued to turn the handle. Once it loosened up enough, I removed the handle and grabbed the conical cover itself and unscrewed it. To @pavlo's point, this is fairly awful.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these have a nut on the bottom side. Unccrew the nut and supply line and pull it up. Many times plumbers putty is there to seal easily cleaned off with a razor blade.

Answer (score 0):

Turning the handle counter clockwise won't do anything, the handle will be unscrewed and loose, but the cover cones will still be stuck. Pulling it up is also not an option as there is a connection going to the side there, which won't let it pass up through the hole. So your only option is to unscrew a thing which is perfectly round and polished. This is dumb engineering and pita for somebody trying to do it. I've managed to do it with a combination of luck, penetrating oil a hose clamp and a combination wrench. I put open clamp through the ring side of the wrench, then closed the clamp and put in on the cone cover. Then used the wrench as the leverage while holding the piece from the bottom with the other hand and unscrewed it.